# incorrect signature verification ethers.utils.verifyMessage()

Tags: ethereumjs

I'm developing a login system using ethers js and when checking the signature on the backend the result of the signature is not the expected wallet
[image]

my function

```
async auth({params, request, response, auth, view}){
        const user = await User.first('wallet', params.wallet);
        const verify = ethers.utils.verifyMessage(user.nonce, params.signature);
        if(verify == params.wallet){
            await auth.login(user);
            response.status(200).json({status: "success", msg: "successfully logged in"});
        }else{
            response.status(401).json({status: "error", msg: "internal error"});
        }
    }
```

code used to create signature

```
 async function assinar(){
    const conn = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    if(conn[0]){
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
      const signer = provider.getSigner()
      const wallet = await signer.getAddress();
      console.log(wallet);
    
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/auth/address/"+wallet,
        dataType: "json",
        success: async function (response) {
          const signature = await ethereum.request({ method: "personal_sign", params: [ethers.utils.hexlify(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(response.nonce)), wallet] })
          console.log(signature);

          $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/auth/verify/"+wallet+"/"+signature,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
              console.log('logado')
              //window.location.href = "/logged";
            },error: function (response){
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: response.msg,
                });
            }
          });

        }
      });

    }else{
      Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: "Erro interno 500",
                });
    }


  }
```

nonce = 1baaab86-d3ea-4b3c-aba3-e52c52a430b8

wallet = 0x99B207873b98DeA8e43559aA08349c59B1b0Ad28

signature = 0xc316c04db61d853e3e1a22e658dbe254b70caeeaeeee115eb472c2d74455ce1c51452042dd1deceae0633843cd7026c704b5fe282b7722e5f93cb046a6ccb28d1c

exitString = 0x7f06997dc680c8c4d786b6C16eCA2B6774d4183F

Comment: Could you show the content of the signed message ? If possible alongside with the code used to generate the message and signature please.

Comment: I updated the question with the requested content

Comment: I am facing same issue, do u manage to fix this issue ?